# Zeit (Vercel) Now serverless authenticated requests failing because of CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, authorization, serverless, vercel

I'm not able to correctly handle CORS issues when doing either `PATCH`/`POST`/`PUT` requests from the browser sending an `Authorization` header with a `Bearer token` (this works correctly outside of the browser and for `GET` requests) in [Zeit Now serverless](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/introduction).

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for the authorization side if that helps.

---

This is my `now.json` headers section, I've tried a lot of combinations for these, but neither succeeded from the browser.

[image: Headers in now.json]

---

1. I tried using npm `cors` package without success
2. Tried to add `routes` in `now.json`
3. Tried setting headers at the top of the serverless function using `res.addHeader()`
4. Also tried handling `OPTIONS` request manually doing variations of this:

[image: OPTIONS method custom handling]

Finally, this is the error that I get

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.org/api/users' from origin 'https://example.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Not sure what I'm wrong or how to handle this properly.

Comment: What does your complete now.json look like?

Comment: Add a middleware using `app.use()` within index.js <br/>
Need an example? follow [this](https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to bypass this issue using [micro-cors](https://github.com/possibilities/micro-cors).

I checked [its code](https://github.com/possibilities/micro-cors/blob/master/src/index.js) and it doesn't differ that much of what I attempted to do myself by using `res.setHeader` manually, probably missed something I guess.

Nevertheless I don't understand why the settings in `now.json` were not working correctly and I need to perform this manually in the serverless function.

Anyways, in case someone else finds this post, I ended up with something like this:

```js
import micro from "micro-cors";

function MyApi(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.status(200).end();
  }
  // handling other requests normally after this
}

const cors = micro();

export default cors(MyApi);
```

I'll probably will try again with a self-written solution in order to understand better what went wrong and also because I don't want an extra dependency.

Will update this answer if I do that.

---

**Edit:** After checking a bit deeper I found that another issue was the library `express-jwt` specifically changing the `res` object when the `jwt` parse failed.

I had a small middleware that was breaking everything by doing:

```js
await authValidateMiddleware(req, res);
```

When that `await` failed, it broke everything down the line because `express-jwt` changed the `res` headers unknowingly (setting the error) and then I tried to set the `res` headers manually trying to handle the error correctly myself, therefore throwing issues about *"changing the `res` headers more than once"*.

Comment: Do you have another solution for this? I am also having a problem with cors.

Comment: @keisaac are you using any express middlewares? For auth or something like that? If so those middlewares also change the `res` object so you may need to workaround those

Comment: I am not using express, I am following the guide on Vercel using helpers. I end up using setHeader, but I encountered another problem by having undefined if I'm trying to access the body.

Answer (score 6):

I have pretty much similar issues with CORS and Vercel serverless function.

After lots of **try → failed** process I just found solutions for this.

---

## Solutions

### tldr

The simplest solution, just using [micro-cors](https://github.com/possibilities/micro-cors).

And having an implementation something like;

```
import { NowRequest, NowResponse } from '@now/node';
import microCors from 'micro-cors';

const cors = microCors();

const handler = (request: NowRequest, response: NowResponse): NowResponse => {
  if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return response.status(200).send('ok');
  }

  // handle incoming request as usual
};

export default cors(handler);
```

---

### Longer version, but without any new dependency

using `vercel.json` to handle request headers

`vercel.json`

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/.*",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value": "*"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After self tried, there are **2 keys important** in an above setting,

1. You must set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as what you want
2. In `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` you **must include** `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` into its value.

then in serverless function, you still need to handle [pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) as well

`/api/index.ts`

```
const handler = (request: NowRequest, response: NowResponse): NowResponse => {
  if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return response.status(200).send('ok');
  }

  // handle incoming request as usual
};
```

---

I would suggest to read through the code in [micro-cors](https://github.com/possibilities/micro-cors), it's very simple code, you can understand what it'll do in under few minutes, which makes me didn't concern about adding this into my dependency.

Comment: Thank you, to remind me out that I forget to handle the preflight request. +1

Comment: Glad this could make a help :)

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem and the problem was solved byadding the header to the routes as follows:

```
"routes": [
    {
      "src": ".*",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      },
      "dest": "index.js",
      "continue": true
    },
    {
      "src": "/user/login", "methods": ["POST"], "dest": "index.js"
    }
  ]
```

remember to add `continue: true`.

https://github.com/super-h-alt/zeit-now-cors-problems/blob/master/now.json

Comment: Can this also be achieved by axios? or must it be a JSON file?

Comment: Thank you! The headers seem to be sent, but I'm getting a 500 ERROR whenever a post request is made now. Would you mind checking out my now.json and my server.js at https://codepen.io/mattfrancis888/pen/vYNPRZW?

Answer (score 4):

I was in pretty much the same situation. I have a couple of serverless functions in Vercel (Now) and I wanted them to be available to anyone at any origin. The way I solved is similar to [@illiteratewriter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407820/8737022).

First, I have the following `now.json` at the root of my project:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      },
      "continue": true
    },
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "methods": ["OPTIONS"],
      "dest": "/api/cors"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a breakdown of the two routes configurations:

```
{
  "src": "/api/(.*)",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
  },
  "continue": true
}
```

- `"src": "/api/(.*)"`

Matches any request going to `/api/*`.

- `"headers": [...]`

Applies the CORS headers to the route, indicating that CORS is allowed.

- `"continue": true`

Continues looking for other route matches after applying the CORS headers. This allows us to apply the CORS headers to *all* routes, instead of having to do it per-route. For example, now `/api/auth/login` and `/api/main/sub/resource` will both have the CORS headers applied.

```
{
  "src": "/api/(.*)",
  "methods": ["OPTIONS"],
  "dest": "/api/cors"
}
```

What this config does is to intercept all `HTTP/OPTIONS` requests, which is the CORS pre-flight check, and re-route them to a special handler at `/api/cors`.

The last point of the routes configuration breakdown leads us to the `/api/cors.ts` function. The handler looks like this:

```js
import {NowRequest, NowResponse} from '@now/node';

export default (req: NowRequest, res: NowResponse) => {
  return res.status(200).send();
}
```

What this handler does is basically accept the CORS pre-flight `OPTIONS` request and respond with `200/OK` to it, indicating to the client **"Yes, we are open for CORS business."**

Comment: Do you have to create the now.JSON? can this be done via axios?

Comment: @MatthewFrancis I am not sure exactly what you mean by doing it with axios. Can you please elaborate? I have only used axios as a client-side library for making HTTP requests. Here it's all about server-side code and receiving, and handling such requests. However, if you want to configure CORS for Vercel serverless functions then creating `now.json` is the only way (that I know of so far).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me.  However vercel now appear to have [updated their advice](https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-to-enable-cors), with their example code being:

```js
const allowCors = fn => async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  // another option
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
  )
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end()
    return
  }
  return await fn(req, res)
}

const handler = (req, res) => {
  const d = new Date()
  res.end(d.toString())
}

module.exports = allowCors(handler)
```

It's worth saying I'm not entirely sure of the difference between `res.end` and `res.send` but to actually ingest the response into my front end (React) I changed the `handler` function to:

```js
const handler = (req, res) => {
        const d = {data: "Hello World"}; 
        res.send(d)
}
```

which allowed me to ingest in React as:

```js
function getAPIHelloWorld () {
    let connectStr = "/api"
    fetch(connectStr)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {console.log(response.data)})
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was facing the same issue and it worked for me by applying the following  code inside vercel.json

```
{
"version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/app.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/app.ts",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I was missing the **"OPTIONS"** and **"PATCH"** methods, after I added them everything works fine.

And to mention, this is how I'm using **cors** , hope this answer helps somebody

```
app.use(cors({ origin: ['http://localhost:3000', /\.regenci\.online$/], credentials: true }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this could help, I faced the same issue and tried several ways (middleware handler, headers in vercel.json, etc) and none of the above seemed to work **until I deleted the project from Vercel and deployed it again.**

Then I tried to modify the allowed origin and the CORS failed again, until I deleted the project from Vercel and deployed again with this new config.

=> Seems that if you modify the CORS settings after initial deployment, Vercel may see it as a diff in config (as seen per *an alert in the settings of the project*) and for some reason CORS setting will not function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of other answers here is what has worked for me.

```
.env
FRONT1="https://odin-book-front.vercel.app/"
FRONT2="https://odin-book-front.vercel.app"

app.js
var express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const allowedOrigins = [process.env.FRONT1, process.env.FRONT2];
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: function (origin, callback) {       
            if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
                callback(null, true);
            } else {
                callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
            }
        },
        credentials: true,
        })
      );

vercel.json
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
{
"src": "./app.js",
"use": "@vercel/node"
}
],

"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/api/(.*)",
        "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    },
    "dest": "app.js",
    "continue": true
},
{
    "src": "/api/(.*)",
    "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "dest": "app.js"
}
    ]
}
```

I was getting errors like:
"blocked by CORS policy" "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" "It does not have HTTP ok status"
and
Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.